# Is it true that $\operatorname{tr}(AA') - (l_1 ^2 + \dots + l_n ^2) > 0$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to know if for a matrix with real entries the next inequality holds:

$$\operatorname{tr}(AA') - (|l_1| ^2 + \dots + |l_n| ^2) > 0$$

where $l_1, \dots, l_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

I have tested a few matrices with success and I know that the modulus of an  eigenvalue is bounded above and below by singular values.

Comment: Hi. I fixed your latex. Also, can you please show what you've done so far in order to solve this, so we can give you a direction?

Comment: What is $A'$, the transpose?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, you have equality.

Comment: It is possible to solve this using the Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality.

Comment: It feels so good to see that somebody actually cares about my question! Thank you for fixing my latex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality holds even for complex matrices, if one uses absolute value and $A^*$ instead of $A'$.

If you just use the definition of product, you'll get that 
$$\tag{1}
\text{tr}(AA')=\sum_{k,j=1}^n |A_{kj}|^2.
$$

Let $A=VTV^*$, with $T$ triangular and $V$  unitary (via the Schur Decomposition). The diagonal entries of $T$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Then
$$
\text{tr}(AA')=\text{tr}(VTV^*VT'V^*)=\text{tr}(VTT'V^*)=\text{tr}(TT'V^*V)=\text{tr}(TT').
$$
Using $(1)$,
$$
\text{tr}(AA')=\sum_{k,j=1}^n |T_{kj}|^2\geq\sum_{k=1}^n|T_{kk}|^2=|l_1|^2+\cdots+|l_n|^2.
$$
The inequality need not be strict, as $A$ can be selfadjoint.

Comment: You write 'as $A$ can be diagonal' - don't we already have equality if $T$ is diagonal, i.e. $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes, I should have written "selfadjoint".

Comment: I have two questions thou: Why $ Tr(VTT'V^\star) = Tr(TT'V^\star V)$ and for a matrix with complex values one should use $A^\star$ instead of $A'$ right?

Comment: Probably using $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ with $A = VT$ and $B = T'V^\star$ one can obtain $tr(VT T'V^\star) = tr(T'V^\star VT) = tr(T'T)$ ... or something similar?

Comment: Yes. And, of course, if $A$ is complex we need to use $A^*$ instead of $A'$.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please consider upvoting it; that's the way reputation is earned on this site.

Comment: I pressed the upwards arrow next to the answer but it says that I do not have enough reputation to make any difference :)

Comment: No worries. If you stay participating in the site, you'll soon have reputation :)